# Get data and images in different threads

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, imageview, loader

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from Google Books API (  https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=1). I'm using Loaders to do this and there's no problem getting data like title, author or description but it spends a lot of time retrieving the string url of the thumbnail image and convert it to bitmap. So I want to do this last operation in another thread, that is, load all data (included the string url) and then convert the string to bitmap and set the ImageView in another thread. Any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: please share the code you have

Comment: You just have to learn how to use AsymcTask. There are a lot of guide, tutorials and examples online.

Comment: this is the repo https://github.com/miguelbarra/BookListingApp